# Close on socket's input stream takes too long

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

We are having a problem every now and then with one of our clients, whose connections get disconnected after a specific time. The exception on the client side shows a "Read Timed out" message. Since we do not use socket timeouts in our Java application (we use the default values of 0), our first thought is that the client's timeouts must be coming from a proxy or router on the their side. Their IT department is looking into this problem.

However, when the connection is aborted, our client application closes the socket and then  establishes a new connection to our server. Upon the reception of a new connection from the same client, the server will initiate a cleanup operation on the old connection before it starts using the new one. That cleanup happens either when the server detects an EOS or any other read exception or when a new connection is accepted by the same client and the old one has not been cleaned-up for whatever reason (this is what happens here due to our server failing to detect an EOS). That cleanup operation includes actually some logging, clearing of various routing data structures and the final closing of the input and output streams. At that point we have observed, that the close of the input stream of the old socket blocks for 15 minutes and the time is always the same. As you can understand, then everything goes wrong because the new connection starts starving and the same problem starts from the beginning repeatedly.

Now, I suppose that our socket on the server side is suffering from an indefinite FIN_WAIT_2 or TIME_WAIT state, in which the socket remains in one of those states without receiving the necessary ACKs (perhaps they are dropped), which could move it to CLOSED state. Although our server was not the one to break the connection in the first place, I suppose it is the proxy or router at the customer's side, which may have initiated and made it look like our server's close. I have read that setting the SO_LINGER option on the server side to 0 could help in such a situation (although it is not recommended in general). FYI: we haven't messed so far with the SO_LINGER option but we are thinking of doing so, due to the problem.

Could you please explain me whether that theory be true? Moreover, why does make the socket close operation take 15 minutes? This is way beyond the normal 2 * MSL (Maximum Segment Lifetime) duration, which is supposed to be the time for which the socket is waiting for a close. Should we perhaps set the value of the SO_LINGER option (setSoLinger method in Java) to a value higher than 0? In any case, the client has already aborted the connection on the other side and as such, setting the linger option to 0 just before closing the socket would not result in any other exception or wrong state on the client side. Moreover, are you are of any tools out there, with which we could simulate dropped packets in our environment?

The code doing the socket creation and cleanup is nothing special. Here is a snippet:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress, port);
OutputStream dataOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream(), 64000);
InputStream dataInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream(), 64000);
```

Stream closing code

```
 try {
       if (dataInputStream != null) {
          LOGGER.info("Going to close input stream....");
          dataInputStream.close();
       }
    } finally {
       if (dataOutputStream != null) {
          LOGGER.info(".closeReaderWriter()", "Going to close output stream...");
          dataOutputStream.close();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share code where you instantiate the socket, where you close the socket, and where you attempt to reengage it again?

Answer (score 0):

Closing the input stream of a socket closes the socket and the output stream, without flushing it. The only actual operation in this that affects the socket is closing it. Closing a socket is asynchronous unless you have messed around with the SO_LINGER option, so normally the situation you describe cannot possibly arise.

Conclusion: you have messed around with the SO_LINGER option.

Solution: don't.

You say the server can't detect the client problem until he reconnects.

Conclusion: you aren't closing the socket in the client application when these read timeouts occur.

Solution: close it. Then the server will read EOS, close the socket, and continue on its merry way.

Closing the input stream of a socket is unnecessary. Just close the outermost output stream/writer you've wrapped around the socket output stream to ensure it gets flushed, and perhaps the socket itself in a finally block.

The rest of this raises more questions than answers.

1. How have you 'completely disabled the socket timeouts in your Java application'?
2. You say your server is 'cleaning up' but you also say it 'hasn't initiated a close in the first place'. Why not?

Comment: Hi EJP. First of all thanks for your answer. I may have not been clear in the beginning. Please look at my edited question for answers on your questions.

Comment: Hi EJP. Our client application does a close on the socket but our server fails - for whatever reason - to detect the EOS. And this is where our assumptions are based for some weird reaction on the customer's proxy. If the proxy drops the FIN or RST packages sent to us, then our server is unable to detect the situation. I also don't believe that the close is an asynchronous operation. A close must also wait for some ACKs from the client side. If these ACKs are dropped, then the close takes long. Java's source code on close has comments warning about possible long operations.

Comment: You appear to be claiming that DataInputStream.close() takes 15 minutes. It doesn't. So what does? Your question remains unclear.

Comment: Since you appear to be absolutely persuaded about the fact that DataInputStream.close() should perform asynchronously, I will try to take again a more careful look at our logs. I will let you know!!!

Comment: I looked again into our server logs. There is a log statement before DataInputStream.close() logging out intention to close the input stream and afterwards another log before DataOutpuStream.close(), logging out intention to close the input stream. The difference between the 2 log statements (both coming from the same thread!!!) is 15 minutes. There is no doubt about that!!! What could cause this delay? Couldn't it be the proxy or router dropping some messages?

Comment: What *else* happens between the log messages? There's no doubt about what the manual pages say, or about the behaviour I've been observing for about 22 years.

Comment: As I have already said. This is happening only for 1 of our customers. We are not experiencing this problem for any other and we have not experienced something like this for 13 years of operation. It is new for us as well. In the original question, you can find a direct copy-paste of our socket closing code.